# running command line program from npyscreen select option

Tags: python

I have a npyscreen program which has set of options and also I have another normal python command line program which interacts with user by asking yes/no question(s) like a wizard.

I want to integrate the normal python command line program in to the npyscreen program, so when user selects a option I want to run this normal python program. I do not want to reimplement the whole normal python command line program into npyscreen.

Is there anyway to do?

I found one function "npyscreen.CallSubShell" but didn't find any example code and much help in the documentation about this function.

Thanks in advance for any help.

/Shan

Comment: looks like npyscreen.CallSubShell have a bug. os.system is used to run the command we pass but 'os' module is not imported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

npyscreen has CallSubShell function which allows to execute a command line program. The CallSubShell is actually switching from curses mode to normal mode and executes the command using os.system then at the end of the command execution switches back to curses mode.

Note:- I was not able to make the standard input working properly in the command execution. Also you may want to clear the screen before calling CallSubShell.

Comment: #curses.endwin() # Probably causes a memory leak.    This line was commented due to probable memory leak. If we uncomment this line then we were able to get the input working.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the solution Shan. This works for me. Also as you said, uncommenting curses.endwin() works for scripts that are interactive.